# How to change the default collation of a table?

Tags: mysql, sql, collation

```
create table check2(f1 varchar(20),f2 varchar(20));
```

creates a table with the default collation `latin1_general_ci`;

```
alter table check2 collate latin1_general_cs;
show full columns from check2;
```

shows the individual collation of the columns as 'latin1_general_ci'.

Then what is the effect of the alter table command?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change database collation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5906585/change-database-collation)

Comment: You may wish to alter the correct answer as myself and many others seem to agree that the 2nd one is the correct one.

Answer (score 676, accepted):

To change the default character set and collation of a table *including those of existing columns* (note the **convert to** clause):

```
alter table <some_table> convert to character set utf8mb4 collate utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

Edited the answer, thanks to the prompting of some comments:

> Should avoid recommending utf8. It's almost never what you want, and often leads to unexpected messes. The utf8 character set is not fully compatible with UTF-8. The utf8mb4 character set is what you want if you want UTF-8. – Rich Remer Mar 28 '18 at 23:41

and

> That seems quite important, glad I read the comments and thanks @RichRemer . Nikki , I think you should edit that in your answer considering how many views this gets. See here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-unicode-utf8.html and here [What is the difference between utf8mb4 and utf8 charsets in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30074492/772035) – Paulpro Mar 12 at 17:46

Comment: What are the implications of changing the default character set? Does it update existing data and therefore need to run through the table and make updates, locking it, etc.?

Comment: `utf8_bin` is better, isn't? What's the difference between `utf8_bin` and `utf8_unicode_ci`?

Comment: That's just an example I used. The difference is that `utf8_bin` is case-sensitive and `utf8_unicode_ci` is case-insensitive. One isn't necessarily better than the other -- use whatever suits your needs.

Comment: @JasomDotnet you should now use utf8mb4_unicode_ci http://stackoverflow.com/questions/766809/whats-the-difference-between-utf8-general-ci-and-utf8-unicode-ci

Comment: Should avoid recommending `utf8`.  It's almost never what you want, and often leads to unexpected messes.  The `utf8` character set is not fully compatible with UTF-8.  The `utf8mb4` character set is what you want if you want UTF-8.

Comment: That seems quite important, glad I read the comments and thanks @RichRemer . Nikki , I think you should edit that in your answer considering how many views this gets. See here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-unicode-utf8.html and here https://stackoverflow.com/q/30074492/772035

Answer (score 36):

MySQL has 4 levels of collation: server, database, table, column.
If you change the collation of the server, database or table, you don't change the setting for each column, but you change the default collations.

E.g if you change the default collation of a database, each new table you create in that database will use that collation, and if you change the default collation of a table, each column you create in that table will get that collation.

Comment: In fact, MySQL has **FIVE** Levels of collation, there is a character set level default collation setting that many people forget about.

Comment: There's also connection collation `show variables like "collation%";`, so total is ***SIX***.

Answer (score 9):

It sets the default collation for the table; if you create a new column, that should be collated with latin_general_ci -- I think.  Try specifying the collation for the individual column and see if that works.  MySQL has some really bizarre behavior in regards to the way it handles this.

Answer (score 4):

may need to change the SCHEMA not only table

```
ALTER SCHEMA `<database name>`  DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4  DEFAULT COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci ;
```

as Rich said - utf8mb4

(mariaDB 10)

Comment: `<database name>` instead of `<table name>`

Comment: See my comment on the accepted answer why you shouldn't recommend `utf8`, but `utf8mb4`.