# MySQL Workbench Error 1005: Can't create table (errno: 150)

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

SQL CODE:

```
SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='TRADITIONAL,ALLOW_INVALID_DATES';

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `db`.`zip_codes` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `db`.`zip_codes` (
  `zip` CHAR(5) NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`zip`)  COMMENT '')
ENGINE = InnoDB;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `db`.`houses` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `db`.`houses` (
  `house_id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT '',
  `zip` CHAR(5) NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  `user_id` INT(11) NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`house_id`)  COMMENT '',
  INDEX `fk_houses_users1_idx` (`user_id` ASC)  COMMENT '',
  INDEX `fk_houses_zip_codes1_idx` (`zip` ASC)  COMMENT '',
  CONSTRAINT `fk_houses_users1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`)
    REFERENCES `db`.`users` (`user_id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_houses_zip_codes1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`zip`)
    REFERENCES `db`.`zip_codes` (`zip`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT = 24
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = latin1;

SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;
```

The error I am getting:

```
Executing SQL script in server
ERROR: Error 1005: Can't create table 'db.zip_codes' (errno: 150)
SQL Code:
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `db`.`zip_codes` (
          `zip` CHAR(5) NOT NULL COMMENT '',
          PRIMARY KEY (`zip`)  COMMENT '')
        ENGINE = InnoDB

SQL script execution finished: statements: 4 succeeded, 1 failed
```

In one of the lines I noticed that it says INDEX `fk_houses_zip_codes1_idx` (`zip` ASC)  COMMENT '', I took out the ASC part and it still produced the same error. I know the 1500 error comes up when the foreign key reference is incorrect or the attribute type isnt the same. I double checked all these reasons and nothing seems wrong. Does anyone have any idea what I am doing wrong?

EDIT: User table

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `db`.`users` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `db`.`users` (
  `user_id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT '',
ENGINE = InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT = 23
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = latin1;
```

Comment: Where is your users table? Also you have 3 columns at your error notation but only one in your CREATE query.

Comment: @KostasMitsarakis the user's table has already been created. I reverse engineered my database so that's why I didnt include it. Also I fixed the notation so they match

Comment: Can you also show the user table CREATE query?

Comment: Do you use any triggers?

Comment: no triggers @KostasMitsarakis

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4063141/mysql-foreign-key-error-1005-errno-150?rq=1 and here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15013153/mysql-workbench-forward-engineering-error-1005-cant-create-table-errno-1?rq=1