# Can't create tables in Mysql

Tags: mysql

I have these tables but only managed to create

1. Insurance_Policy_Type
2. Historical_Era
3. Region
4. Reference
5. Organisation
6. Geographic_Area

The rest of them are giving me **errors** such as,

```
"Cant create table" on Loan_Item,
"Reference_Id dont exist" on Historical_Era_Reference
"error 1064 (4200)" on Loan
```

---

```
CREATE TABLE Insurance_Policy_Type (
Insurance_Policy_Type_Id INT (4),
Insurance_Policy_Type_Name VARCHAR (30),
PRIMARY KEY (Insurance_Policy_Type_Id));


CREATE TABLE Historical_Era (
Historical_Era_Id INT (4),
Historical_Era_Name VARCHAR (30),
PRIMARY KEY (Historical_Era_Id));


CREATE TABLE Reference (
Reference_Id INT (4),
Reference_Name VARCHAR (30),
Author VARCHAR (30),
PRIMARY KEY (Reference_Id));


CREATE TABLE Region (
Region_Id INT (4),
Region_Name VARCHAR (30),
PRIMARY KEY (Region_Id));

CREATE TABLE Organisation (
Organisation_Id INT (4),
Organisation_Name VARCHAR (30),
PRIMARY KEY (Organisation_Id));

CREATE TABLE Items (
Item_Id INT (4),
Item_Name VARCHAR (30),
Description VARCHAR (30),
Insurance_Policy_Type_Id INT (4),
Geo_Area_Id INT (4)
PRIMARY KEY (Item_Id),
FOREIGN KEY (Insurance_Policy_Type_Id) REFERENCES Insurance_Policy_Type(Insurance_Policy_Type_Id),
FOREIGN KEY (Geo_Area_Id) REFERENCES Geographic_Area(Geo_Area_Id));

CREATE TABLE GeoArea_HistEra (
Geo_Area_Id INT (4),
Historical_Era_Id INT (4),
FOREIGN KEY (Geo_Area_Id) REFERENCES Geographical_Area(Geo_Area_Id)),
FOREIGN KEY (Historical_Era_Id) REFERENCES Historical_Era(Historical_Era_Id));

CREATE TABLE Historical_Era_Reference (
References_Id INT (4),
Historical_Era_Id INT (4),
FOREIGN KEY (Reference_Id) REFERENCES Reference (Reference_Id),
FOREIGN KEY (Historical_Era_Id) REFERENCES Historical_Era (Historical_Era_Id));


CREATE TABLE Loan_Item (
Item_Id INT (4),
Loan_Id INT (4),
FOREIGN KEY (Item_Id) REFERENCES Items(Item_Id),
FOREIGN KEY (Loan_Id) REFERENCES Loan(Loan_Id));

CREATE TABLE Geographic_Area (
Geo_Area_Id INT (4),
Geo_Area_Name VARCHAR (30),
Region_Id INT (4),
PRIMARY KEY (Geo_Area_Id),
FOREIGN KEY (Region_Id) REFERENCES Region (Region_Id));

CREATE TABLE Loan (
Loan_Id INT (4),
Item_Id INT (4)
Organisation_Id INT(4)
Loan_Start DAY,
Loan_End DAY
FOREIGN KEY (Organisation_Id) REFERENCES Organisation (Organisation_Id),
FOREIGN KEY (Item_Id) REFERENCES Items (Item_Id));
```

Comment: what error message do you get?

Comment: 1st create the table with out Foreign key.
once you create the table alter the table for adding Foreign key.

Comment: First of all there is typo in the sql above. You have missed one "," in Items table after Geo_Area_Id that's why it is showing you error like this and as others are saying you can try adding constraints manually and make sure you are using InnoDB Engine.

Answer (score 2):

Try to create the tables first and add the Foreign Keys later.

Comment: *voted up* so you can place reactions in further cases. Welcome to SO.

Comment: Hey guys, thank you all for your contributions, they were really helpful. you even opened my eyes to concentrate. Most of the errors I had were because of typos, missing " , ", having extra " ) " and not declaring Primary key. I hop this will also help somebody. ~ THANKS

Comment: @user2357469 you can edit your answer pasting the final correct code that you came up with. Also, if my suggestions did help you, please accept my answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of issues with the query above.

1. You are making a reference to a table which doesn't exist yet: `"FOREIGN KEY (Geo_Area_Id) REFERENCES Geographic_Area(Geo_Area_Id));"` First create the table and then update the foreign keys.
2. There are plenty of syntax errors - missing commas and double brackets. Instead of pointing them one by one, I'd suggest learning how to spot them, for example I suggest using an IDE. I personally test statements in MySQL Workbench.
3. The query will likely produce an error 150, for a number of reasons. Please see a very good summary on typical errors with primary keys as FK [in the first answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9018584/error-code-1005-cant-create-table-errno-150).