# MySQL, can't create foreign key

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, mysql-workbench

```
    create table movie(

    movieTitle varchar(40)
            not null

,   yearReleased year
            check (not year > year(current_date))

,   movieLength int(3)
            null

,   constraint coPKmovie
    primary key (movieTitle, yearReleased)
);

create table person(

    personName varchar(40)
            not null

,   secondName varchar(40)
            not null

,   dateOfBirth datetime
            not null

,   yearCareerStarted year
            not null
            check (not year > year(current_date))

,   bornCountry char(03)
            not null

,   constraint coPKperson
    primary key (personName, secondName)
);

create table participant(

    partPersonName varchar(40)
            not null

,   partSecondName varchar(40)
            not null

,   movieTitle varchar(40)
            not null

,   jobTitle varchar(30)
            not null

,   constraint coPKpart
    primary key (partPersonName, partSecondName, movieTitle, jobTitle)

);


alter table participant
    add constraint partFKname foreign key (partPersonName)
    references person (personName)

,   add constraint partFKSecond foreign key (partSecondName)
    references person (secondName)

,   add constraint partFKmovie foreign key (movieTitle)
    references movie (movieTitle)

    on delete cascade
    on update cascade;
```

Can somebody explain why I always get an error while I want to create foreign key from table participant, partSecondName to table person , secondName. I don't want to hear why I don't use any id in my database, I just practising without them. Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: The FK on the person is wrong, you should place a single constraint on both name and second name at the same time, not separate one.

Comment: thank you very much Matteo Tassinari, it work now! oh, now I will know :) thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"8. One of the fields in the relationship is part of a combination (composite) key and does not have it’s own individual index. Even though the field has an index as part of the composite key, you must create a separate index for only that key field in order to use it in a constraint."

See this old post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9018584/error-code-1005-cant-create-table-errno-150).