# Error 1005: Can't create table can't find where the issue is

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, eer-model

I have created a EER model using MySQL Workbench (latest release). Apparently all is fine but when I try to do a FORWARD ENGINEER I get the common **Error 1005: Can't create table**. As suggested in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9018584/error-code-1005-cant-create-table-errno-150) I check every step on the first answer but without success, can any give some extra eyes to my query and try to find where my error is? I can't see it.

This is the error generated by the tool:

```
Executing SQL script in server
```

> ERROR: Error 1005: Can't create table
>   'portal_de_logistica.order_has_comment' (errno: 150)

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `portal_de_logistica`.`order_has_comment` (
  `user_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `no_order` VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
  `comment` TEXT NOT NULL,
  `created_at` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`, `no_order`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_fos_user_rnd`
    FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`)
    REFERENCES `portal_de_logistica`.`fos_user_user` (`id`)
    ON DELETE RESTRICT
    ON UPDATE RESTRICT,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_tb_order_rnd`
    FOREIGN KEY (`no_order`)
    REFERENCES `portal_de_logistica`.`tb_order` (`no_order`)
    ON DELETE RESTRICT
    ON UPDATE RESTRICT)
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8
COLLATE = utf8_unicode_ci
```

And this is the complete SQL sentences:

```
SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='TRADITIONAL,ALLOW_INVALID_DATES';

DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS `portal_de_logistica` ;
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `portal_de_logistica` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 ;
USE `portal_de_logistica` ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `portal_de_logistica`.`company`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `portal_de_logistica`.`company` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `portal_de_logistica`.`company` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  `register_date` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `country` CHAR(3) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `portal_de_logistica`.`contact`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `portal_de_logistica`.`contact` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `portal_de_logistica`.`contact` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `company_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `lastname` VARCHAR(90) NOT NULL,
  `c_position` VARCHAR(150) NULL,
  `email` VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_contact_company1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`company_id`)
    REFERENCES `portal_de_logistica`.`company` (`id`)
    ON DELETE RESTRICT
    ON UPDATE RESTRICT)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE INDEX `fk_contact_company1_idx` ON `portal_de_logistica`.`contact` (`company_id` ASC);


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `portal_de_logistica`.`tb_order`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `portal_de_logistica`.`tb_order` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `portal_de_logistica`.`tb_order` (
  `no_order` VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
  `company_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `business_case` VARCHAR(15) NULL,
  `charge_status` ENUM('0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8') NOT NULL COMMENT '0: Ninguno\n1: Proceso de Fabricacion\n2: Pickup en destino\n3: A la espera de recojo por cliente\n4: Carga en transito\n5: Carga arribada\n6: En proceso de aduana\n7: Entregado a cliente\n8: En bodega',
  `eta` DATE NULL,
  `etd` DATE NULL,
  `transport_media` ENUM('0','1','2') NOT NULL COMMENT '0: EXW\n1: Maritimo' /* comment truncated */ /*2: Aereo*/,
  `incoterm` ENUM('0','1','2','3','4') NULL COMMENT '0: Ninguno\n1: EWX\n2: FOB\n3: CIF' /* comment truncated */ /*4: DDP*/,
  PRIMARY KEY (`no_order`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_order_company1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`company_id`)
    REFERENCES `portal_de_logistica`.`company` (`id`)
    ON DELETE RESTRICT
    ON UPDATE RESTRICT)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX `no_order_UNIQUE` ON `portal_de_logistica`.`tb_order` (`no_order` ASC);

CREATE INDEX `fk_order_company1_idx` ON `portal_de_logistica`.`tb_order` (`company_id` ASC);


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `portal_de_logistica`.`fos_user_group`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `portal_de_logistica`.`fos_user_group` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `portal_de_logistica`.`fos_user_group` (
  `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci' NOT NULL,
  `roles` LONGTEXT CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci' NOT NULL COMMENT '(DC2Type:array)',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8
COLLATE = utf8_unicode_ci;

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX `UNIQ_583D1F3E5E237E06` ON `portal_de_logistica`.`fos_user_group` (`name` ASC);


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `portal_de_logistica`.`fos_user_user`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `portal_de_logistica`.`fos_user_user` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `portal_de_logistica`.`fos_user_user` (
  `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci' NOT NULL,
  `username_canonical` VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci' NOT NULL,
  `email` VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci' NOT NULL,
  `email_canonical` VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci' NOT NULL,
  `enabled` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL,
  `salt` VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci' NOT NULL,
  `password` VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci' NOT NULL,
  `last_login` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `locked` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL,
  `expired` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL,
  `expires_at` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `confirmation_token` VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci' NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `password_requested_at` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `roles` LONGTEXT CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci' NOT NULL COMMENT '(DC2Type:array)',
  `credentials_expired` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL,
  `credentials_expire_at` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  `updated_at` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  `date_of_birth` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `firstname` VARCHAR(64) CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci' NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `lastname` VARCHAR(64) CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci' NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `website` VARCHAR(64) CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci' NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `biography` VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci' NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `gender` VARCHAR(1) CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci' NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `locale` VARCHAR(8) CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci' NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `timezone` VARCHAR(64) CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci' NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `phone` VARCHAR(64) CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci' NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `facebook_uid` VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci' NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `facebook_name` VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci' NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `facebook_data` LONGTEXT CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci' NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '(DC2Type:json)',
  `twitter_uid` VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci' NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `twitter_name` VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci' NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `twitter_data` LONGTEXT CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci' NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '(DC2Type:json)',
  `gplus_uid` VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci' NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `gplus_name` VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci' NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `gplus_data` LONGTEXT CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci' NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '(DC2Type:json)',
  `token` VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci' NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `two_step_code` VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci' NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8
COLLATE = utf8_unicode_ci;

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX `UNIQ_C560D76192FC23A8` ON `portal_de_logistica`.`fos_user_user` (`username_canonical` ASC);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX `UNIQ_C560D761A0D96FBF` ON `portal_de_logistica`.`fos_user_user` (`email_canonical` ASC);


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `portal_de_logistica`.`fos_user_user_group`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `portal_de_logistica`.`fos_user_user_group` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `portal_de_logistica`.`fos_user_user_group` (
  `user_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `group_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`, `group_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_B3C77447FE54D947`
    FOREIGN KEY (`group_id`)
    REFERENCES `portal_de_logistica`.`fos_user_group` (`id`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_B3C77447A76ED395`
    FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`)
    REFERENCES `portal_de_logistica`.`fos_user_user` (`id`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8
COLLATE = utf8_unicode_ci;

CREATE INDEX `IDX_B3C77447A76ED395` ON `portal_de_logistica`.`fos_user_user_group` (`user_id` ASC);

CREATE INDEX `IDX_B3C77447FE54D947` ON `portal_de_logistica`.`fos_user_user_group` (`group_id` ASC);


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `portal_de_logistica`.`media__gallery`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `portal_de_logistica`.`media__gallery` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `portal_de_logistica`.`media__gallery` (
  `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci' NOT NULL,
  `context` VARCHAR(64) CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci' NOT NULL,
  `default_format` VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci' NOT NULL,
  `enabled` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL,
  `updated_at` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  `created_at` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8
COLLATE = utf8_unicode_ci;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `portal_de_logistica`.`media__media`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `portal_de_logistica`.`media__media` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `portal_de_logistica`.`media__media` (
  `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci' NOT NULL,
  `description` TEXT CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci' NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `enabled` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL,
  `provider_name` VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci' NOT NULL,
  `provider_status` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `provider_reference` VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci' NOT NULL,
  `provider_metadata` LONGTEXT CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci' NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '(DC2Type:json)',
  `width` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `height` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `length` DECIMAL(10,0) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `content_type` VARCHAR(64) CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci' NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `content_size` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `copyright` VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci' NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `author_name` VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci' NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `context` VARCHAR(64) CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci' NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `cdn_is_flushable` TINYINT(1) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `cdn_flush_at` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `cdn_status` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  `created_at` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8
COLLATE = utf8_unicode_ci;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `portal_de_logistica`.`media__gallery_media`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `portal_de_logistica`.`media__gallery_media` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `portal_de_logistica`.`media__gallery_media` (
  `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `gallery_id` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `media_id` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `position` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `enabled` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL,
  `updated_at` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  `created_at` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_80D4C541EA9FDD75`
    FOREIGN KEY (`media_id`)
    REFERENCES `portal_de_logistica`.`media__media` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_80D4C5414E7AF8F`
    FOREIGN KEY (`gallery_id`)
    REFERENCES `portal_de_logistica`.`media__gallery` (`id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8
COLLATE = utf8_unicode_ci;

CREATE INDEX `IDX_80D4C5414E7AF8F` ON `portal_de_logistica`.`media__gallery_media` (`gallery_id` ASC);

CREATE INDEX `IDX_80D4C541EA9FDD75` ON `portal_de_logistica`.`media__gallery_media` (`media_id` ASC);


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `portal_de_logistica`.`fos_user_user_has_company`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `portal_de_logistica`.`fos_user_user_has_company` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `portal_de_logistica`.`fos_user_user_has_company` (
  `fos_user_user_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `company_id` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`fos_user_user_id`, `company_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_fos_user_user_has_company_fos_user_user1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`fos_user_user_id`)
    REFERENCES `portal_de_logistica`.`fos_user_user` (`id`)
    ON DELETE RESTRICT
    ON UPDATE RESTRICT,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_fos_user_user_has_company_company1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`company_id`)
    REFERENCES `portal_de_logistica`.`company` (`id`)
    ON DELETE RESTRICT
    ON UPDATE RESTRICT)
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8
COLLATE = utf8_unicode_ci;

CREATE INDEX `fk_fos_user_user_has_company_company1_idx` ON `portal_de_logistica`.`fos_user_user_has_company` (`company_id` ASC);

CREATE INDEX `fk_fos_user_user_has_company_fos_user_user1_idx` ON `portal_de_logistica`.`fos_user_user_has_company` (`fos_user_user_id` ASC);


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `portal_de_logistica`.`order_has_media__media`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `portal_de_logistica`.`order_has_media__media` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `portal_de_logistica`.`order_has_media__media` (
  `order_no_order` VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
  `media__media_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`order_no_order`, `media__media_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_order_has_media__media_order1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`order_no_order`)
    REFERENCES `portal_de_logistica`.`tb_order` (`no_order`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_order_has_media__media_media__media1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`media__media_id`)
    REFERENCES `portal_de_logistica`.`media__media` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE INDEX `fk_order_has_media__media_media__media1_idx` ON `portal_de_logistica`.`order_has_media__media` (`media__media_id` ASC);

CREATE INDEX `fk_order_has_media__media_order1_idx` ON `portal_de_logistica`.`order_has_media__media` (`order_no_order` ASC);


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `portal_de_logistica`.`order_has_comment`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `portal_de_logistica`.`order_has_comment` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `portal_de_logistica`.`order_has_comment` (
  `user_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `no_order` VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
  `comment` TEXT NOT NULL,
  `created_at` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`, `no_order`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_fos_user_rnd`
    FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`)
    REFERENCES `portal_de_logistica`.`fos_user_user` (`id`)
    ON DELETE RESTRICT
    ON UPDATE RESTRICT,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_tb_order_rnd`
    FOREIGN KEY (`no_order`)
    REFERENCES `portal_de_logistica`.`tb_order` (`no_order`)
    ON DELETE RESTRICT
    ON UPDATE RESTRICT)
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8
COLLATE = utf8_unicode_ci;

CREATE INDEX `fk_fos_user_user_has_tb_order_tb_order1_idx` ON `portal_de_logistica`.`order_has_comment` (`no_order` ASC);

CREATE INDEX `fk_fos_user_user_has_tb_order_fos_user_user1_idx` ON `portal_de_logistica`.`order_has_comment` (`user_id` ASC);


SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that `tb_order` doesn't specify a charset or collation like the other tables so will use the database default.

If the default is different from `utf8` and `utf8_unicode_ci` then the foreign key on a text field wont work.