# Error Code: 1005 Can't create table users (errno: 150)

Tags: mysql, sql

When I run this query:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `users`;
```

Then:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `role_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '4',
  `email` varchar(120) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `password_hash` char(60) NOT NULL,
  `reset_hash` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_login` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `last_ip` varchar(40) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `created_on` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `deleted` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `reset_by` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `banned` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `ban_message` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `display_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
  `display_name_changed` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `timezone` char(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'UM6',
  `language` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'english',
  `active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `activate_hash` varchar(40) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `password_iterations` int(4) NOT NULL,
  `force_password_reset` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `email` (`email`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I get error:

> Error Code: 1005
>   Can't create table 'admin_sc.users' (errno: 150)

Checked /var/lib/mysql/admin_sc directory for permission - can create table with other name, but can't create table `users`

Any can help ? No any foreign keys in my query.

Comment: The query itself works.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error Code: 1005. Can't create table '...' (errno: 150)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9018584/error-code-1005-cant-create-table-errno-150)

Comment: Please read [this link](http://verysimple.com/2006/10/22/mysql-error-number-1005-cant-create-table-mydbsql-328_45frm-errno-150/) or [this one](http://blog.mclaughlinsoftware.com/2010/01/30/decoding-1005-on-mysql/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$ perror 105
OS error code 105:  No buffer space available
$
```

Are you sure you drop "users", not "bf_users" ?

Also maybe just InnoDB tablespace is broken. I would try same on another machine to see if problem is repeatable. At least works for me:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> create database testt;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.04 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> use testt;
Database changed
MariaDB [testt]> CREATE TABLE `users` (
    ->   `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    ->   `role_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '4',
    ->   `email` varchar(120) NOT NULL,
    ->   `username` varchar(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    ->   `password_hash` char(60) NOT NULL,
    ->   `reset_hash` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
    ->   `last_login` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
    ->   `last_ip` varchar(40) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    ->   `created_on` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
    ->   `deleted` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    ->   `reset_by` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
    ->   `banned` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    ->   `ban_message` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    ->   `display_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
    ->   `display_name_changed` date DEFAULT NULL,
    ->   `timezone` char(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'UM6',
    ->   `language` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'english',
    ->   `active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    ->   `activate_hash` varchar(40) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    ->   `password_iterations` int(4) NOT NULL,
    ->   `force_password_reset` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    ->   PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    ->   KEY `email` (`email`)
    -> ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (1.33 sec)

MariaDB [testt]>
```

Comment: You right, i published this query with error, but i tried many possible options - don't work (((. Now i find external key from other table to table users, but not found until now.

Answer (score 0):

I Suggest that you execute a script that drops the table "users" ( to check if it's not already exist ) and then Recreate the table

Or as Nishanthi said .. try to Create this table with a different name , it might work

Answer (score -1):

In **my** opinion,It could be because `users` table is reserved for some system related tables.

1. Either change the table name from `users` to something else.
2. Or change your drop table command to `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS users` and then create the table.

Comment: I did it. No results. No file with name users.frm in directory: /var/lib/mysql/admin_sc

Comment: I can create table `users1` , but table `users` can't create

Comment: Then, it is because 'users' is reserved table. If you drop it, may be the DB itself will corrupt and so, you do not have permissions for dropping it / creating in such a name.

Comment: Try my first option provided. You can upvote and accept as answer, since it helped you

Comment: No, 'users' it not reserved.

Comment: @TõnuSamuel: I just said, It COULD BE because it is reserved. I have also given alternatives what has to be done. Why downvote?