# Error 1005 Can't create table for adding a foreign key

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship

I've two InnoDB tables in a MySQL database. Now I like to link one table to the other with a `FOREIGN KEY`. But it aborts with the error code `1005 - Can't create table`.

I've found plenty of information about this error. For example this post and [answer here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9018753/1652031). Although even this answer did not help in my case. I think every point which is mentioned to be checked is not true in my case.

I've created a MySQLFiddle you can checkout with the schema which fails: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b9dc43

(Please note that the failing `ALTER TABLE` for adding the `FOREIGN KEY` is not included. See the schema below for the FOREIGN KEY query.)

There's also a FK for `cms_element_instance.page_IDFK` which references column `page.ID` but I removed this FK for posting my problem here on SO.

What can be the problem here?

Here the schema in plain text:

```
CREATE TABLE `cms_element_instance` (
 `ID` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `page_IDFK` mediumint(8) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
 `revision` varchar(16) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
 KEY `page_IDFK` (`page_IDFK`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1692 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `element_faq_list` (
 `element_instance_IDFK` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `page_IDFK` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `mod_faq_collection_IDFK` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`element_instance_IDFK`,`page_IDFK`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


-- Create FK: This throws error 1005
ALTER TABLE element_faq_list
ADD CONSTRAINT element_instance_fk
FOREIGN KEY (element_instance_IDFK, page_IDFK)
REFERENCES cms_element_instance( ID , page_IDFK);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are adding `(element_instance_IDFK, page_IDFK)` as a foreign key constraints which refers to `ID , page_IDFK` columns from `cms_element_instance` so for this case you need a primary key based on `ID , page_IDFK` columns

```
ALTER TABLE `cms_element_instance` CHANGE `page_IDFK` `page_IDFK` 
MEDIUMINT(8) UNSIGNED NOT NULL, DROP PRIMARY KEY, 
ADD PRIMARY KEY (`ID`, `page_IDFK`);
```

### [`Demo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6b97db)

Comment: I'm fairly sure a UNIQUE key is enough, but you're right, you need a key on the referenced field combination.