# Creating a table in Mysql with phpadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, create-table

I keep getting errors when trying to create a  products table for a  database I'm building.

Here is the code I've tried:

```
CREATE TABLE Products (
    ProductId int NOT NULL auto_increment primary key,
    Name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    Price decimal(19, 4),
    on_hand integer, 
    supp_id int,
    FOREIGN KEY (supp_id) REFERENCES Suppliers(supp_id)
);
```

I am  getting this error code:

> #1005 - Can't create table 'computer_wholesale.products' (errno: 150

Any help would be  greatly appreciated.

Comment: Check this possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4061293/mysql-cant-create-table-errno-150

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9018753/4576237). Ensure that your foreign key has the exact same type as the primary key

Comment: still  getting the  same error :(

Answer (score 1):

I believe your `Suppliers` table is missing an index, which is required to use a `FOREIGN KEY` with.

Comment: `computer_wholesale` is the database name