# error #1005 - Can't create table `testdb`.`blog` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")?

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE TABLE blog
(
    blog_id BIGINT(255),
    email VARCHAR(255),
    blog_title CHAR(255),
    blog_content TEXT(5000),
    PRIMARY KEY (blog_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (email) REFERENCES detail(email)
);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error Code: 1005. Can't create table '...' (errno: 150)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9018584/error-code-1005-cant-create-table-errno-150)

Answer (score 0):

[This link can solve your problem](http://verysimple.com/2006/10/22/mysql-error-number-1005-cant-create-table-mydbsql-328_45frm-errno-150/)