# trouble creating table using foreign key

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys

```
create table department
(
dept_name varchar(20), 
building varchar(20), 
budget numeric(12, 2), 
primary key(dept_name)
);
```

This is table that i created before...

now i am writing this:

```
create table course
(
course_id varchar(7), 
title varchar(50), 
dept_name varchar(20), 
credits numeric(2, 0), 
primary key(course_id), 
foreign key (dept_name) references department
);
```

an it shows :

> ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table 'satyarth.course' (errno: 150)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9018584/error-code-1005-cant-create-table-errno-150) SO question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a portion of the FOREIGN KEY requirement, as you cannot simply refer to another table:

```
foreign key (dept_name) references department(dept_name)
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the reference table field name PFB

```
create table course(course_id varchar(7), 
title varchar(50), 
dept_name varchar(20), 
credits numeric(2, 0), 
primary key(course_id), 
FOREIGN KEY (`dept_name`) REFERENCES `department` (`dept_name`)    
);
```