# error 1005, "Can't create table - SQLAlchemy to MySQL

Tags: mysql, sqlalchemy

Trying to connect to MySQL from Flask-SQLAlchemy but receive

> sqlalchemy.exc.InternalError: (pymysql.err.InternalError) (1005, "Can't create table ql12255647.member_courses... when typed command db.create_all()

When i use `sqlite:////tmp/test.db` everything is fine and no errors

Need to solve problem. My code is below:

```
member_courses = db.Table('member_courses',
      db.Column ('member_id', db.String (80), db.ForeignKey('member.id')),
      db.Column ('course_id', db.String (80), db.ForeignKey('course.id')))

class Course(db.Model):
     id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
     course = db.Column(db.String(80), unique = True)

class Member(db.Model):
     id = db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key=True)
     name = db.Column(db.String(80), unique = True)
     email = db.Column(db.String(80), unique = True)
     courses = db.relationship('Course', secondary='member_courses', 
     backref='member', 
     lazy = 'dynamic')
```

Error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.InternalError: (pymysql.err.InternalError) 
(1005, "Can't create table 'sql12255647.member_courses' (errno: 150)") 
[SQL: '\nCREATE TABLE member_courses (\n\tmember_id VARCHAR(80), \n\tcourse_id VARCHAR(80), \n\tFOREIGN KEY(member_id) REFERENCES member (id), \n\tFOREIGN KEY(course_id) REFERENCES course (id)\n)\n\n']
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/2j85)
```

Comment: Please post the full text of the error you're getting

Comment: Dear Mikhail, please have o look

Comment: The referencing columns have type VARCHAR(80), while the referenced columns have INTEGER. You don't get errors in SQLite because it has a very different type system from most other SQL DBMS, and it doesn't even enforce foreign key integrity by default (it has to be enabled).

Answer (score 2):

Error Code 1005 refers to table creation failure because a `Foreign Key constraint was not correctly formed`. To solve this error, you likely just have to ensure that your foreign key has the exact same type as the Primary key.

The accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9018584/error-code-1005-cant-create-table-errno-150) provides a detailed overview of scenarios that you can verify.

Hope this helps.