# 1005 mysql cannot create table foreign key erno 150

Tags: mysql, magento, create-table

I am trying to create a table based on the Magento database structure. I keep getting an error during my install process, so I am trying to create the three tables associated with the issue. I keep getting an error with the OAuth installation. The new version of Magento divides the process into 3 tables in MySQL. So two of the three tables have been created and here is the MySQL script for the third one - here is the table that runs the error.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `oauth_token`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `oauth_token` (
`entity_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Entity ID',
`consumer_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'Consumer ID',
`admin_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Admin user ID',
`customer_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Customer user ID',
`type` varchar(16) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Token Type',
`token` varchar(32) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Token',
`secret` varchar(32) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Token Secret',
`verifier` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Token Verifier',
`callback_url` varchar(255) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Token Callback URL',
`revoked` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Is Token revoked',
`authorized` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Is Token authorized',
`created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP COMMENT 'Token creation         timestamp',
PRIMARY KEY (`entity_id`),
UNIQUE KEY `UNQ_OAUTH_TOKEN_TOKEN` (`token`),
KEY `IDX_OAUTH_TOKEN_CONSUMER_ID` (`consumer_id`),
KEY `FK_OAUTH_TOKEN_ADMIN_ID_ADMIN_USER_USER_ID` (`admin_id`),
KEY `FK_OAUTH_TOKEN_CUSTOMER_ID_CUSTOMER_ENTITY_ENTITY_ID` (`customer_id`),
CONSTRAINT `FK_OAUTH_TOKEN_ADMIN_ID_ADMIN_USER_USER_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`admin_id`)         REFERENCES `admin_user` (`user_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
CONSTRAINT `FK_OAUTH_TOKEN_CONSUMER_ID_OAUTH_CONSUMER_ENTITY_ID` FOREIGN KEY     (`consumer_id`) REFERENCES `oauth_consumer` (`entity_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE     CASCADE,
CONSTRAINT `FK_OAUTH_TOKEN_CUSTOMER_ID_CUSTOMER_ENTITY_ENTITY_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`customer_id`) REFERENCES `customer_entity` (`entity_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='OAuth Tokens';
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
```

so what should I do or how can I alter the MySQL script to work?

Comment: Can you post the create statements for the tables you are referencing in the foreign key constarints?

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL "ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table 'foo.#sql-12c_4' (errno: 150)"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2799021/mysql-error-1005-hy000-cant-create-table-foo-sql-12c-4-errno-150)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most commonly this is because the tables you are referencing are MyISAM and you can't use them in an FK relationship.

Might also be that you don't have unique names for your FK's but that looks unlikely given your naming convention.

If neither of those, check the columns you are referencing and make sure they have an index on them, either primary key or unique.

Finally check your data type, it must be exactly the same between both columns in the FK relationship. even differing lengths (int(10), int(11)), or signed vs unsigned will not allow you to make an FK relationship.

Comment: Solved! Thank you everyone for your help! The admin-id was set to mediumint(9) ! That was the only thing that needed to get fixed! Thank you thank you thank you!