# Foreign Key in MySQL : ERROR 1005

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys

I'm a bit confused about adding foreign keys in MySQL

What I'm trying to do is reference the Students primary key with:

```
CREATE TABLE Enrolled(sid CHAR(20), cid CHAR(20), grade CHAR(2), PRIMARY KEY (sid, cid), FOREIGN KEY (sid) REFERENCES Students);
```

However, what I get is

```
ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table 'test_db.Enrolled' (errno: 150)
```

I searched around and found

[MySQL "ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table 'foo.#sql-12c_4' (errno: 150)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2799021/mysql-error-1005-hy000-cant-create-table-foo-sql-12c-4-errno-150)

However, my Students table already has a primary key so this should not be an issue:

```
| Students | CREATE TABLE Students (
  sid char(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  name char(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  login char(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  age int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  gpa float DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (sid)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
```

I feel like I'm missing something fairly basic but I can't appear to spot it. Any advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add referenced column name after referenced table 
`REFERENCES Students(sid)`. So you have to change your code to below solution

```
CREATE TABLE Enrolled
(
  sid CHAR(20), 
  cid CHAR(20), 
  grade CHAR(2), 
  PRIMARY KEY (sid, cid), 
  FOREIGN KEY (sid) REFERENCES Students(sid)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

What about making the referenced column explicit? Something like:

```
CREATE TABLE Enrolled(
     sid CHAR(20), 
     cid CHAR(20), 
     grade CHAR(2), 

     PRIMARY KEY (sid, cid), 
     FOREIGN KEY (sid) REFERENCES Students (sid)
);
```

Look at `FOREIGN KEY (sid) REFERENCES Students (sid)`, last line. Also note that if the foreign key is a single column you can specify it just after the column type:

```
CREATE TABLE Enrolled(
    sid CHAR(20) REFERENCES Students (sid), 
    ...
```