# How to change foreign key referencing in mysql?

Tags: mysql

Suppose, I have `item(name, code, price, provider)` and `provider(name, code, address)`

I make `item` table using

```
CREATE TABLE item 
(
  name varchar(50) NOT NULL, code varchar(30) NOT NULL, price float NOT NULL, provider varchar(50) not null,
  PRIMARY KEY(code),
  foreign key(provider) references provider(name)
);
```

But, now I want something like `foreign key(provider) references provider(code)`.

Comment: Can you give some examples of what you've tried to achieve this, and what effect you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Check that all the conditions for creating a FK are met - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html

Answer (score 1):

If you need to remove the previous constraint you can do:

```
ALTER TABLE item
drop foreign key item_ibfk_1
```

'item_ibfk_1' is the fk symbol corresponding to your original constraint. To find this fk symbol for your table, you can run following command:

```
SHOW CREATE table item;
```

Then you need to add the new constraint

```
ALTER TABLE item
ADD FOREIGN KEY(provider) REFERENCES provider(code);
```

Comment: `mysql> alter table item add foreign key(provider) references provider(code);
ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table 'handicraftstore.#sql-52d_7b' (errno: 150)`

Comment: That is a different error. I tried the query that I posted, and it worked for me. Maybe this can help you: [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2799021/mysql-error-1005-hy000-cant-create-table-foo-sql-12c-4-errno-150)

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
ALTER TABLE item
ADD FOREIGN KEY(code) REFERENCES provider(code);
```

**Note:** You have to make sure that the provider.code and provider.name are unique keys. MySql allows foreign keys constraints only for unique or primary key columns.

Comment: `item.code` is not foregn key, it is primary key. `item.provider` is foreign key referencing `provider.code`

Comment: I have commented another answer. Please check it out and let me know if it was helpful.