# how to change the db collation in mysql

Tags: mysql, database

I need to add this `Boženy němcové 2148/12` in mysql database but it shows some error like this `0 rows affected.
Warning: #1366 Incorrect string value: '\xC4\x9Bmcov...' for column 'Address' at row 1` how can i fix this error ?

Im using `latin1_swedish_ci` db collation and how to fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As answered previous [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5906585/how-to-change-the-default-collation-of-a-database)

Change column collation

```
ALTER TABLE <table_name> MODIFY <column_name> VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use
`ALTER SCHEMA SCHEMA_NAME DEFAULT COLLATE utf8_bin;`

Then you will be needing `Alter` table as
`ALTER TABLE SCHEMA_NAME.TABLE_NAME 
CHARACTER SET = DEFAULT;`