# PHP Myadmin Unicode_520 Not in Dropdown list - missing, how do i add it?

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

I am trying to change unicode in my phpmyadmin as instructed below:
*PhPMyAdmin=>Choose your database=>Click your database=>Operations=>Collation=>utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci=>GO.* 
However, I dont have unicode_520 in my dropdown box, can i add this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change the default collation of a database?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5906585/how-to-change-the-default-collation-of-a-database)

Comment: @cmorrissey - I don't think that's an appropriate duplicate. Making the change via PHPMyAdmin's GUI as opposed to writing a query distinguishes this question enough not to close it for that reason.

Comment: @HPierce the phpMyAdmin install is controlled by the OPs hosting solution and can not be modified by him (screenshot was removed showing this), which is why I marked this with this solution.

Comment: Which MySQL version are you using? This should be a factor of your MySQL configuration, not phpMyAdmin itself.