# change database encoding

Tags: php, mysql, character-encoding

Can anybody helps me in how to change the encoding of the database, because when I try to execute the following query :

```
 $stmt=$conn->prepare("INSERT INTO photo (id_user,name) VALUES(:id_user,:name)");
    $stmt->execute(array(
        "id_user" => 1,
        "name" => 'allèèeeâ'
        ));
```

In the database I get the following result : allÃ¨Ã¨eeÃ¢. I tried to run the following command to solve the problem :

```
ALTER DATABASE databasename CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
ALTER TABLE tablename CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
```

But it did not solve the problem.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Try with this query : http://stackoverflow.com/a/30223807/4952944. it may be work.

Comment: Are you connecting via putty or similar? If so ensure the putty character encoding isn't confounding your error, when the data is actually stored and retrieved correctly.

Comment: I'am using wamp server (Apache).

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored ; look for "Mojibake".