# Using utf-8 in an webpage isn't working properly

Tags: mysql, utf-8, windows-1252, collate

I have a mysql database using latin1_swedish_ci collation on the table.
I will present this data on a web page.
I'm trying to use charset=utf8 on the web page that shows the result, but it gives me a lot of strange chars as ? and other instead of the swedish å,ä,ö,chars.

I've tried to use different sql commands to change the data to be "printed".
All with bad results. (Collate f.e.)

I am not the original coder for this site and the charset is set to windows-1252.

It works when using this charset (windows-1252), but every native char as å,ä,ö needs to be translated/written as å ,ä ö in the html code for the strings in the html code to be right.

[a lot of ?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l6E2G.png) When using charset=utf-8

It would be great to get a solution for this.
To get the latin1_swedish_ci mysql table to work together with a web page using charset=utf-8 that is.

Using Collate in sql statements.
Like this example
SELECT k COLLATE latin1_german2_ci AS k1
FROM t1
ORDER BY k1;

Comment: See question marks in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored

Answer (score 1):

The thing with transcoding between different charsets is that it's not a magic trick. There are things you can't do. However, you can simply transcode your entire database to soemthing that is much more suitable to handle UTF8.

Using WAMP (or simply PHPMyAdmin):

1. Select your database in the explorer on the left
2. Click on the Operations tab
3. Go at the very bottom and select `utf8_unicode_ci` (or `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`)
4. Check the option for all tables
5. Check the option for all columns
6. Execute
7. You're all set to use utf8

Otherwise, you can follow the instruction in the answers of [How to change the CHARACTER SET (and COLLATION) throughout a database?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5906585/7316365) for a pure SQL solution.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I've been thinking about this option. Is it safe to transpose in this way? No risk for data being corrupt? Will the characters still be swedish, including the å, ä, ö and so on?

Comment: If you want you can always make a backup before doing it, reverting the charset and collate change and then restoring the backup. As they're in the unicode tables it should all be fine. You'd have issue going from a limited charset to another different limited one

Comment: Great suggestion with the backup. That is a necessity. What do you mean with limited charset? This is not my specialty, but I'm keen on understanding it better.

Comment: Unicode isn't that limited, but charset like windows-1252 or ASCII are extremely limited in the number of characters