# Dealing with spanish tilde in Golang

Tags: mysql, utf-8, go

So I'm trying to enter this string into a mysql database using a sql driver. I get this error -

```
Do?a Merced Elementary
panic: Error 1366: Incorrect string value: '\x96a Mer...' for column 'name' at row 1
```

I thought about excluding this entry, but haven't been able to do so. I've tried -

```
if !strings.ContainsAny(splitStr[2], "U+0303") {
if !strings.ContainsAny(splitStr[2], '\x96') {
```

but that has not worked.

It would be better to have mysql deal with this, but I'm not sure how.

Any suggestions?

EDIT

This is how I connect to my db

```
db, err := sql.Open("mysql", "psanker:123@/education_data")
err = db.Ping()

db.SetMaxOpenConns(0)
check(err)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Failed to prepare connection to database")
    log.Fatal("Error:", err.Error())
}
```

This is where my issue comes

```
districtResult, err := db.Exec("INSERT INTO districts(name) VALUES(?)", strings.TrimSpace(splitStr[2]))
check(err)
```

Output of SHOW CREATE TABLE

```
---------------------------------+
| Table     | Create Table                                                                                                                                                                                                                   |
+-----------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| districts | CREATE TABLE `districts` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=35 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci |
```

Comment: what is Collation in field of table.?

Comment: It's this latin1_swedish_ci

Comment: I think the long-term best thing to do here is convert your input from MacRoman to UTF-8, because UTF-8 is a more widely used and more flexible encoding. You can call a program called `iconv` to do it, and there are library bindings to call iconv functionality from Go code. I'm not sure which is the best, but [`github.com/qiniu/iconv`](https://godoc.org/github.com/qiniu/iconv) came up on a search. Unfortunately I don't have time to come up with the full steps to use it on your input here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please change collation to `utf8_general_ci`. it should work

Comment: how do I do that? I already tried http://stackoverflow.com/questions/742205/how-to-change-the-default-collation-of-a-table, and it didn't work

Comment: Won't work because the 96 is encoded in "macroman", not utf8.

Answer (score 0):

Running on an Apple?  I assume that should have said `Doña Merced Elementary`?  Yet, to get `ñ` from x96, you must have started with text in the "MacRoman" encoding.

The simple solution *might* be to do `SET NAMES macroman` right after connecting to MySQL.

Comment: I did that and it said 0 rows were affected

Comment: That establishes that macroman is the encoding on the _client_ side.  So, perhaps the data is already stored wrong?  Please run `SELECT col, HEX(col) FROM tbl WHERE ...` to see what is actually in the table.

Comment: Find the "mysql commandline tool" or "phpmyadmin".  Construct a `SELECT` statement similar to what I wrote, but reaching for Doña.  Run it.  Report back on what you see.

Comment: Let's see the code by which you are connecting to the database.

Comment: there is no Dona in the table - that's the first time I'm inserting, I'll post the go code used to connect and insert into the db.

Comment: There may be a row with just `Do` (truncated).  Or perhaps the insert aborted without doing anything.  Anyway, please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.